# how to drag in the animation in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, animation, methods, drag

Iphone application is using the static co-ordinates to reach at some points in the application,which is based on the button event.
But what i want is when i drag the item than it should reach at some point where i drop it and again from the drop point it should move to the other point.

can anybody guide me what is the method available in the iphone animation part which can serve my pupose.?

please provide any method code snippet for Drag the item or any useful link,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal shah.

Comment: Please, clarify: You want to drag an item and after dropping it should be moved onto a certain place on the screen (which doesn't has to be the drop point), right?

Comment: i want to first drag from 1 point and what to drop on desired point.One it droped at any point after that point will be used at the drag point and move to other point as drop.
can u pls give me the method which can be used here and how to make the points for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Apple's [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/index.html) sample - it shows how to drag the objects.